# Inserting into a many to many relation in room

Tags: android, sql, android-asynctask, many-to-many, android-room

I am currently building an android app, that uses a small database which consists of two entity-data-classes (Card and CardDeck) and a third one representing a many to many relationsship between the former two by mapping there long id primary keys together (CardInCardDeckRelation).

Now I want to insert a new Deck into my database, which works just fine, but if I want to insert some CardInCardDeckRelation-objects afterwards by using the id returned from the insertCardDeck()-method it fails because the insertion calls on the relationship-table occur before the insertion of the cardDeck object is finished so I am always getting the wrong cardDeck-id.

I think I am going into the right direction by using a Async-task to insert my CardDeck however I don't know to proceed from there since I can only pass one set of Arguments to my async-task object, so I can't pass my Relationshipobjects to be inserted in say for example a onPostExecute-method in the Async-task-class.

This my insert-method in my Repository-class:

```
public void insertCardDeckAsync(CardDeck cardDeck){
    new insertAsyncTaskDao(mCardDeckDao).execute(cardDeck);
}

private static class insertAsyncTaskDao extends AsyncTask<CardDeck, Void, Void> {

    private CardDeckDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    insertAsyncTaskDao(CardDeckDao dao){
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final CardDeck... params){
        mAsyncTaskDao.insertCardDeck(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
        //maybe insert Relationship object here?
    }
}
```

I would be very thankful if someone could provide a way to properly insert an entity object and some many-to-many relationsship objects afterwards, using the id generated by the former insert.

Answer (score 0):

So after some testing i figured out my error:
I was initially using an Executor which I defined somewhere else in my App to handle database operations, so I don't have to create a private inner class extending AsyncTask for every database operation in my Repository class.
For some reason though my usage of Executor does seem to block the particular thread when executing database-queries so:

```
mExecutors.diskIO().execute(new Runnable(){
    //insert new Deck

    //insert Many-to-Many relationsship-object
}
```

would execute both operations immediately after one another, thus causing a SQL-ForeignConstraint-related error, because it tries to insert the realtion objects before the actual deck object is inserted.

The solution to this is to just use a AsyncTask instead, handling all the database operation in the right order in the doInBackground-method:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final CardDeck... params){
        // insert new deck object into database
        insertionId = mAsyncTaskDao.insertCardDeck(params[0]);

        // create relations-array
        CardInCardDeckRelation[] relations = new CardInCardDeckRelation[STANDARD_CARDS.length];

        // insert standard-card objects into array
        for(int i = 0; i < STANDARD_CARDS.length; i++){
            relations[i] = new CardInCardDeckRelation(insertionId,
                    mAsyncCardDao.getStandardCardByName(STANDARD_CARDS[i]),
                    i);
        }

        // insert created array into database
        mRelationDao.insertMultiple(relations);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Deck inserted");
        return null;
    }
```

If anyone needs further explanation I can provide the whole AsyncTask class.